# Rotation and measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I do not know how to prove part $e$

By d) we know that each rectangle is sent to a rectangle with same measure i.e. $m^*(TR)=m^*(R)$, which implies $TE$ and $E$ will have the same outer measure.

But how to show $TE$ is actually measurable? The hint mentions regularity, but I can only think of the vitali cover from part b: for each rectangle, we have a countable union of disjoint closed discs, together with a zero set. So for the countable cover consisting of rectangles, each rectangle includes a countable union of disjoint closed discs, and countable union of countable closed discs is countably many closed discs, which seems to form the $F_\sigma$ set, but where is the $G_\delta$ set needed? (not sure how to prove those countably many closed discs are subset of $TE$ or $E$)

Or if we denote $V_k$ as the closed discs, $\cup V_k$ converges to $TE$, (also pairwise disjoint). Is this enough to say $TE$ is measurable?

Comment: Can someone help?